# pass an array of strings from c# to Excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, marshalling, vba

My situation: I'm creating a library using C# that will be called from Excel using VBA code. There's a C# method "SubscribeCallBack" which will receive an address of a VBA Procedure (Function Pointer) and marshal the function pointer into a C# delegate. Let me explain more:

In the C# library there's a variable to store a typed delegate:

```
public delegate bool TDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string str);
TDelegate CallBack = null;
```

This delegate will run upon some event:

```
someObj.SomeEvent += (object sender, EventArgs args) => {
    if (CallBack != null)
        CallBack(someString);
};
```

And a method exposed to VBA code to set the CallBack:

```
public void SetCallBack(int callBackAddress) {
    try {
        CallBack = (TDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
            new IntPtr(address), typeof(TDelegate));
        }
}
```

Now after the compiled C# library is loaded as a Excel AddIn, I can call C# methods using Application.Run(). I can write this:

```
Application.Run("SetCallBack", AddressOf VBACallBack)

Public Function VBACallBack(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Cells(1, 1).Value = str
    MsgBox "VBACallBack Running"
    VBACallBack = True
End Function
```

Now things work as expected: I can see VBACallBack got executed when it should be.

Now finally comes the question: I put `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)]string` as C# delegate parameter so that the VBA Function with a single string argument can be Marshaled to this typed delegate. Now I need to pass a Function from VBA like this into a C# delegate:

```
Function(stringArray() As String) As Boolean
```

taking a String array (or any other thing containing an ordered list of String to make it work)
How exactly can I do this? I tried with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)]string[]` and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]string[]` both are not working.

Comment: Did you try `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_BSTR)]   
   String[]` ? based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays

Comment: yes I think must be this! will update if it works

Comment: no it doesn't work :( @rene

Comment: from within VBA, the function receives an invalid thing